# Установка SSL сертификата для сайта, сервер Apach 2.4, Windows

Tags: windows, apache, ssl

Столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу подключить SSL сертификат на сайт, хотя вроде бы всё выполняю по инструкции. Сертификат бесплатный от DomainSSL. DNS идёт через Cloudflare (стоит пункт на настройке SSL Flexible).
Что сделал:

1. В httpd-ssl.conf добавил это:

```
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
    DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"
    ServerAdmin *****
    ErrorLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/error.log"
    TransferLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/access.log"
    ServerName www.****.ru
    ServerAlias ****.ru
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "C:/Apache24/conf/new***.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/Apache24/conf/newprivate.key"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "C:/Apache24/conf/newchain.crt"
```

2. В httpd.conf включил модуль из пункта 1.

В итоге на локалхост соединение не защищено, а на самом домене отображается сертификат от Cloudflare, который мне не подходит. Если кто разбирается, то подскажите, что доделать и/или переделать, пожалуйста.

Comment: Сам факт наличия SSL Flexible говорит о том, что через Cloudflare идёт не только DNS, но и вообще весь трафик — а значит всегда будет сертификат именно от Cloudflare

Comment: Есть настройки:
Full - Encrypts end-to-end, using a self signed certificate on the server И
Full (strict) - Encrypts end-to-end, but requires a trusted CA or Cloudflare Origin CA certificate on the server. 
Но при включении их сайт по https не открывается

Comment: Этих настроек вообще не должно быть. Если вы хотите управлять сертификатами через Apache — вам нужно убрать Cloudflare целиком и полностью

Comment: То есть предлагаете поменять DNS на другой сервис, где можно использовать свой SSL сертификат?

Comment: Если у вас есть эти настройки, значит вы используете Cloudflare не как DNS, а как прокси-сервер, через который идёт весь трафик. Если вам от Cloudflare нужна только функция DNS — значит в настройках DNS-записей переключите "Proxy status" на "DNS only", и тогда весь трафик пойдёт напрямую на указанные вами IP-адреса в обход серверов Cloudflare

Comment: Спасибо, попробуем!